# Linux C++: sys/io.h not found on arm64 but on amd64 it is there

Tags: c++, g++, arm64

I have a Qt C++ project with a dependency to <sys/io.h>. I need to build the project for AMD64 and ARM64. Therefore I use a docker environment to be able to build it with buildx for both platforms. Baseimage is Ubuntu 20.04.
The AMD64 build runs without any issues. But with ARM64 I get a compiler error, that <sys/io.h> could not be found: `No such file or directory`.
What am I missing?

Comment: `What am I missing?` You are nothing missing? It is expected. You should _port_ your application to support different architecture.

Comment: The `<sys/` headers are architecture and OS dependent.  A library depending on anything there is not portable.

Comment: `sys/io.h` contains a number of inline functions for accessing x86 io ports.  ARM has no architectural io ports of this fashion.  You need to look at why your project is including this -- is it a redundancy, or does it actually perform io instructions.   You can test for this either by making an empty `sys/io.h` file and see if your build succeeds, or searching your source for: `in[bwl][^i]|out[bwl]`.  If it is needed, you will have to figure out what hardware you are dependent upon, and how to mimic it in your ARM platform.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Wasn't aware that the sys headers are platform specific.